# Dice roll: Probability of getting a given sum + a particular set of numbers

Tags: probability

The problem goes as: "An unbiased usual six-sided die is thrown three times. The sum of the numbers coming up is $10$. What is the probability that $2$ has appeared at least once?"

Options:

$A. 1/36$

$B. 5/36$

$C. 91/216$

$D. 1/18$

My approach: I understood this as finding the probability of getting at least one $2$ (say event $A$) in each triplet subject to the condition that the sum of the numbers in the triplet $= 10$ (say event $B$). Using the rules of conditional probability,
$P(A|B)=P(A \cap B)/P(B)$

Manually listing all triplets that sum to $10$, I found $P(B)=27/216$ and counting the triplets that had at least one $2$ I found $P(A \cap B)=12/216$. Thus getting the answer $4/9$ which is definitely wrong looking at the options, I've no idea how to go ahead of this.

Comment: @callculus Hey, good catch! I found this question on a test but I wonder how is an examinee supposed to understand with respect to what sample space they want the probability? Looking at the options yours seems the only one correct..

Comment: shelali I was on the wrong way. Sure $P(A\cap B)=\frac1{18}$. But this is only one part. I haven´t calculated $P(B)$ yet. But it seems that you´re right if I look at the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach makes sense, i.e., count the number of ways to roll $10$ with three dice:

$(1,3,6), (1,4,5), (1,5,4), (1,6,3),\\
(2,2,6),(2,3,5),(2,4,4),(2,5,3),(2,6,2),\\
(3,1,6),(3,2,5),(3,3,4),(3,4,3),(3,5,2),(3,6,1),\\
(4,1,5),(4,2,4),(4,3,3),(4,4,2),(4,5,1),\\
(5,1,4),(5,2,3),(5,3,2),(5,4,1),\\
(6,1,3),(6,2,2),(6,3,1)
$

Those are $27$ possibilities, each with equal probability. Of them, $12$ contain a $2$, so that gives us $\frac{12}{27}=\frac49$.

Are you sure there isn't a mistake in the question? None of the given choices are even equivalent to any fraction with $27$ in the denominator. This is suspicous.

Comment: +1. I also got $4/9$, so I'm pretty sure that is the correct answer ...

Comment: The wording is exactly as it was in the original, but maybe they meant 12/216 = 1/18 rather than 12/27.

Comment: @ShefaliPatra:  that would be the correct answer to the question "What is the chance that the sum is $10$ and that at least one $2$ came up?"  I think you have correctly answered the question as asked.

Answer (score 2):

The ways to get a sum of $10$ are as follows:

$$1 + 3 + 6$$
$$1 + 4 + 5$$
$$1 + 5 + 4$$
$$1 + 6 + 3$$
$$\color{green}{2 + 2 + 6}$$
$$\color{green}{2 + 3 + 5}$$
$$\color{green}{2 + 4 + 4}$$
$$\color{green}{2 + 5 + 3}$$
$$\color{green}{2 + 6 + 2}$$
$$3 + 1 + 6$$
$$\color{green}{3 + 2 + 5}$$
$$3 + 3 + 4$$
$$3 + 4 + 3$$
$$\color{green}{3 + 5 + 2}$$
$$3 + 6 + 1$$
$$4 + 1 + 5$$
$$\color{green}{4 + 2 + 4}$$
$$4 + 3 + 3$$
$$\color{green}{4 + 4 + 2}$$
$$4 + 5 + 1$$
$$5 + 1 + 4$$
$$\color{green}{5 + 2 + 3}$$
$$\color{green}{5 + 3 + 2}$$
$$5 + 4 + 1$$
$$6 + 1 + 3$$
$$\color{green}{6 + 2 + 2}$$
$$6 + 3 + 1$$

There are $4 + 5 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 = 27$ total possibilities, of which $12$ involve a two. This gives $$\frac{12}{27}=\boxed{\frac{4}{9}\,}$$

Comment: Thanks for listing them all, that's precisely what I did. But as another user noted in a comment on the question it seems the question asks for the probability with respect to the sample space of 216 instead of the 27 we would​ assume thinking of conditional probability. Fine with that, but I am confused how you understand which sample space to consider then in questions as this? You end up 'wrong' despite a correct approach.

Comment: @ShefaliPatra The question, as it is worded in your post, has an answer of $4/9$ ... I don't know why the answer choices do not include the correct value. Are you sure the question is written correctly?

Comment: This is precisely the copy of the question (I double checked), and the source of the question, as far as I know, shouldn't be erroneous. But often maths questions do get confusingly worded..